# Linear time algorithm

Tags: algorithm

My phone interview question:

There are two departments in a company. Department A has employees E1,E2 and E3. Department B has employees E4,E5 and E1. I have to list all the employees in Department A who are not in Department B ie I must return Department A with E2,E3. I solved it using SQL join query.  What is the best algorithm to solve this in linear time O(n) or logarithmic time O(log n)?

Comment: a basic concept in software engineering is kiss which is keep it simple,.. you are thinking in a more complex way

Comment: You can use `Set` for this.

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing how the inputs are represented.  For example, it can be solved by merging two sorted lists, but not in worst-case linear time unless the inputs have some internal organization that can be exploited.

Comment: why have you tagged java? does it have any specific reason?

Comment: @user3274830 Thanks for your response.Added java tag by mistake. I have removed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm with ***O(n)***:

1. find the number of number of employees [O(n)]
2. create an string for each department as illustrated in the following example [O(n)]
3. xor the two strings of prev. step
4. not the result
5. xor the result with the string corresponding to dept. A
6. bingo! (simply convert the string to set

example:

e1 e2 e3
e5 e1 e4
11100
10011
----- xor
01111
----- not
10000
11100 xor
-----
01100

Answer (score 1):

1. Construct Hashtable for listB(E4,E5 and E1), takes O(n)
2. check listA(E4,E5 and E1) items one by one in hashtable, capture items which are not found in hashtable.(each search takes O(1), total time will be nO(1) = O(n))

Total O(n) +O(n) = O(n)